# Server does't get all the JSON from remote REST API

Tags: json, api, http, go, server

My Go server does not retrieve all the JSON data from a remote API

I even tried creating a custom http.Client to make the request...but still it won't retrieve **ALL** the JSON data,and even tried extending the respective timeouts

Here's my code:

```
var netTransport = &http.Transport{
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout: 50 * time.Second,
        }).Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 50 * time.Second,
    }
    var netClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout:   time.Second * 40,
        Transport: netTransport,
    }
    res, getErr := netClient.Get(url)

    if getErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(getErr)
    }
    data := JSONData{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    data.Username = user
    fmt.Println(data)
```

JSONData is defined as follows:

```
type Owner struct {
    Login string
}

// Item is the single repository data structure
type Item struct {
    ID          int
    Name        string
    FullName    string `json:"full_name"`
    Owner       Owner
    Description string
    CreatedAt   string `json:"created_at"`
}

// JSONData contains the GitHub API response
type JSONData struct {
    Count    int `json:"total_count"`
    Username string
    Items    []Item
}
```

Comment: How did you define `JSONData`?

Comment: Also add the JSON document to the question.

Comment: it's a query to GItHub's API as follows 
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:danvixent (example for my own username)....mine isn't large so it gets all of the json...but for a user like microsoft...it gets only about 30 records.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/

Answer (score 0):

The `JSONData` needs to define JSON tags.

```golang
type Owner struct {
    Login string `json:"login"`
}

// Item is the single repository data structure
type Item struct {
    ID          int    `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    FullName    string `json:"full_name"`
    Owner       Owner  `json:"owner"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    CreatedAt   string `json:"created_at"`
}

// JSONData contains the GitHub API response
type JSONData struct {
    Count    int    `json:"total_count"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Items    []Item `json:"items"`
}
```

---

If no tag is specified, the name is taken as-is:

```golang
type Owner struct {
  Login string
}
```

that would be marshaled (and correspondingly unmarshalled) into similar:

```js
{"Login": "some login"}
```

Comment: No they don't actually...you're only required to do so for the ones you whose corresponding json key are different e.g FulllName and "full_name"...this needs to be associated with a JSON tags...also Peter already gave me the solution i need in a comment above..it's not my code it's a behaviour from GitHub..
But thanks for taking the time to answer my question!!!  

Comment: You're right. I've tried to unmarshal and to my surprise, it worked. Thank you for pointing that out, that's news for me. Still, I think it is usually good to keep tags in there for two reasons. First, you pin the JSON field name, even when the name changes. Second, marshaling without a tag would result in the capital first letter. https://play.golang.org/p/YoZc3yViw-C

Comment: Yeah that is true...Thank you